# Joomla Save Module As Another Copy

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I'm using Joomla 2.5.3.
I have this module that incorporates with authentication. For some reasons I want this module to be duplicated, so I save it as another copy.

Now, as its Module Type is same as the original one,say Auth, how do I customize the files of the copied module?

There is no folder for the copied module inside modules. Only the original one is there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to modify and how the module was created.

- If the module was created using the MVC design pattern you want to modify ONLY the view (layout, html, css, js), then you'll need to check if the module supports multiple views/layouts or override the layout and create a view for each module depending on its Id. http://www.minitek.gr/tutorials/joomla-16-tutorials/item/21-how-to-create-a-new-custom-module-in-joomla-16.html
- If the module wasn't created using the MVC design pattern, you could duplicate the module folder with another name and modify the name of the module in the xml, however it also depends on what the module does (does it write anything to the db?).
- Maybe the easiest (probably not the best), would be modifying the current module depending on the module id. Check this out: http://docs.joomla.org/JModuleHelper/getModule

Answer (score 0):

Think of a module as being similar to a class. You have one instance of the module created already. When you either clone the current instance or create a new instance there is still only one underlying set of files.

Each instance of the module contains its own individual settings so they should not clash with each other.

I can't think of any reason why you would need to customise the underlying files. If you do find a need then your best bet is to copy all of the files from the original module and use them as a base to build your own - entirely new - module, with a new name, new class names, etc.